# Can I set the display on Canon G9X to monochrome when shooting raw?

Tags: canon, raw, black-and-white, monochrome

My old G9 (no X, from 2007 or so) can do this but I remember Canon removing the feature on the G10 and probably from subsequent models. I guess the reasoning was that raw is always in colour anyway. But it helps to have a b/w screen when composing and so on.

I should clarify that I don't own this camera, but I'm thinking about buying it. I know the "picture style" doesn't affect the raw image. Canon also knows this and so they have disabled its use when shooting raw with some models. My old Canon G9 as well as my Fuji X30 and Nikon D600 allows this, but I have seen other cameras where this is not allowed. How about the G9X?

Comment: Does the "G" series feature Picture Styles? (e.g. Standard, Portrait, Landscapes, Neutral, Faithful, Monochrome, etc.)

Comment: @MichaelClark Yes it does. But since they can only be applied to jpegs, I wonder if the screen will show the setting even when shooting raw.

Comment: It's not that difficult to set the camera to save raw files and also select the *Monochrome* Picture Style to see what is displayed on the rear LCD is it?

Comment: @MichaelClark Well, that is my question. I don't have the camera so can't test right now.

Comment: After reading the G9 X manual it is clear that camera does *not* use Canon's *Picture Styles* menu and system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the entire *[Canon PowerShot G9 X User Manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/8/0300020268/01/psg9x-cu-en.pdf)* cover to cover it does not appear that the G9 X will allow you to do what you wish.

The *Image Color Tones (My Colors)* described on page 79 can only be selected when saving images to JPEG only. A note at the bottom of page 90 indicates the following: 
[image: p.90 note]

What isn't exactly clear is what happens if you have selected *B&W* from the *My Colors* menu with the camera set to save JPEGs and then you enable saving both JPEG and RAW files simultaneously. My guess, however, based on the note cited above is that the features listed will be disabled while capturing images both as JPEGs and RAW files.

Comment: Thanks. It never occurred to me to read the manual... embarrassing. I guess the only way to find out is to try it out for real.

Comment: Tried it and your guess is correct.